# beautifulsoup for looping and getting text and Href

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I'm in a bit of a quinch here:

its an ASP site which is really messy that I am trying to get data from:

I'm trying to use a `for` loop to get an `href` and the text of all the rows of the 4th table that is on the site, so I first did:

```
table = soup.findAll('table')[3]
```

Then from this table I need to get all text inside the `<tr>` tags and the `href`'s of the `<a>` inside.

i tried something like this:

```
for product in table.findAll('tbody'):
  product_title = product.find('tr').text
  product_link = product.find('a')['href']
  print (product_title, product_link)
```

But I get nothing in return

The table Im working on:

```
    <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">
  <td>
   <a href="free.asp?detail=hide&amp;c_id=4342141">
    <img align="absmiddle" border="0" hspace="0" src="pic/bullet.gif" vspace="0"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>
   4342141
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   25.07.2018 09:00
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   Ankara
  </td>
  <td width="10">
   -
  </td>
  <td>
   Konya
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF" height="3">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="1">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD" height="6">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="1">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DEE3E7" height="3">
  <td colspan="10">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#DEE3E7">
  <td>
   <a href="free.asp?detail=hide&amp;c_id=4134123">
    <img align="absmiddle" border="0" hspace="0" src="pic/bullet.gif" vspace="0"/>
   </a>
  </td>
  <td>
   4134123
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   26.07.2018 09:00
  </td>
  <td width="10">
  </td>
  <td>
   Van
  </td>
  <td width="10">
   -
  </td>
  <td>
   Istanbul
  </td>
  <td colspan="2">
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show a print of  `product`?

Comment: What does your HTML document look like?

Comment: Please edit your question, without sample HTML/URL we cannot help you much here.

Comment: You had missed indentation in `for` loop block.

Comment: Is there a "tbody" element in the table? It is missing from your HTML. Without it you code will print nothing.

Comment: yes there is an tbody element in the table, I just put a snippet of the code on here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting text from tbody from table, you can directly get all tr tags. 
Based on your snippet you can refer to this code snippet for data extraction from table.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
all_products = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    text = tr.get_text(separator=' ', strip=True)
    if text:
        a_tag = tr.find('a')
        if a_tag:
            product_link = a_tag.attrs['href']
            all_text = text + ' ' + product_link
            all_products.append(all_text.split(' '))

print(all_products)
```

Output is:

```
[['4342141', '25.07.2018', '09:00', 'Ankara', '-', 'Konya', 'free.asp?detail=hide&c_id=4342141'], ['4134123', '26.07.2018', '09:00', 'Van', '-', 'Istanbul', 'free.asp?detail=hide&c_id=4134123']]
```

Comment: The output Im getting is:   File "C:\Users\yasir\Documents\Web Scraping\araba.py", line 41, in <module>
    product_link = a_tag.attrs['href']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
[Finished in 1.8s]